# Get ListView Item Values of row tapped

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Get ListView Item Values of row tapped. I am able to get the item tapped in code behind like so:

```
private async void Item_Tapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = (ListView)sender;
    if (listView != null)
    {
       string pName = e.Item //.PNname; **<<-- This is returning my bound values (4 items) as PName, PNumber... and so on**
    }
}
```

I try to type the .PName it is a sub value to the e.Item list but that is invalid. I really need to grab by name because it appears the return selected row item returns values in a random way? One time PName will be first then next it might be 2nd or 3rd?

Anyway what am I missing to grab the values I need?

I'm doing a lot more visual things here but wanted to keep this code very simple to what I am actually having an issue with getting the individual values in the row.

TIA!
Cheers!
Rick...

Comment: Convert the type of e.Item to your model and then you can access the properties in your model.

Comment: Thank you Jack for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.Item` is an object (datatype), if I am not mistaken. You have to cast `e.Item` to the right data type first:

```cs
string pName = (e.Item as Person)?.PName;
```

(assuming that `PName` is a property of the class `Person`)

Comment: Thanks Saber. I was casting in incorrect way I had been attempting to do a normal cast as: 
string pname = (PInfo)e.item; then use pname.PName to get value

Comment: @Rick You´re welchome ... but that should actually work as long as the cast is valid: `string pName = ((PInfo)e.Item).PName;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try get the itemIndex clicked and get the element in the list or use the AutomationId.